# How to query a JSON field with Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have this models:

```rust
use diesel::sql_types::Json;

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct GMapsLocation {
    pub id: i32,
    pub place_id: String,
    pub data: Json,
}
```

and am trying to query that column like this:

```rust
    let results = gmaps_locations
        .select((id, place_id, data))
        .load::<GMapsLocation>(&connection)
        .expect("Erorr loading locations");
```

And that is not working, giving me the error:

```
18   |         .load::<GMapsLocation>(&connection)
     |          ^^^^ the trait `Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Json, _>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Json`
```

The documentation does not give any examples and this error does not tell me anything.

Comment: what db backend are you using? iirc I think that would only work with postgres one.

Comment: Yeah, this is Postgres.

Comment: @alpher, did you try with [`Jsonb`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/types/sql_types/struct.Jsonb.html)?

Comment: I mean does it matter in the end? Both of the fields should give the same thing. I would be happy even to get it as a `String` at this point.

Comment: It matter is one works but the other doesn't :),  It should work, otherwise you could use String in your schema and `serde_json::Value`. Then implement Queryable yourself and deserialize the value.

Comment: Inserting records does work with this setup, so at least the core database connection is there.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I figured it out.

Just like the input value [from the documentation](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/pg/sql_types/struct.Jsonb.html) is a `serde_json::Value`, the return value from the query is also a `serde_json::Value`. That is also what you have to put in your `Queryable` struct.

I have no clue what `diesel::sql_types::Json` is for then but it should not go in there.

So the working code is:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Debug)]
pub struct GMapsLocation {
    pub id: i32,
    pub place_id: String,
    pub data: serde_json::Value,
}

let results = gmaps_locations
    .select((id, place_id, data))
    .load::<GMapsLocation>(&connection)
    .expect("Erorr loading locations");
```

Comment: did you using rust diesel to do a jsonb query@Alper